# Replace token in text by the filename

Tags: sed, grep

I have a bunch of textfiles that contain the token -filename-. I need to replace it by the real path and filename of the file.

Thats what I have so far:

> grep -lr -e '-filename-' *.txt | xargs sed -i
>   's/-filename-/therealname/g'

Is there a way to replace *therealname* with the name of the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do a bit more bash-fu

```
for x in *.txt; do
    sed -i "s/-filename-/$x/g" $x;
done
```

Of course, the newlines are just for clarity. Feel free to cram that into one line.

Answer (score 2):

like

```
for f in $(grep...) ; do sed -i "s,-filename-,$f,g" $f ; done
```

you mean?

With `xargs` it will be something like this.

```
grep ... | xargs -I% -n 1 sed -i "s,-filename-,%,g" %
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in YOUR_FILE_LIST_MASK ; do
    sed -i "s:-filename-:${f}" ${f}
done
```

can do it.